# Ghost-like artifact when passing image to blur() or Canny() in openCV

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, unity-game-engine, computer-vision

So I have some C++ opencv code that I'm calling from C# inside unity to process the input from the webcam.

I compile my C++ code to a DLL that I then import into C# with a DLLImport. I pass a pinned GCHandle reference to the C++ code so that I can manipulate the image array from C++. This all works. I can pass each frame to my C++ dll and have it grayscale it. It works wonderfully.

The problem arises when I try to do things other than just making the frame grayscale. I tried to do a simple blur() and the output comes out with a weird ghosted image to the left and right. I'm not sure what could be going wrong. It also happens when I do GaussianBlur() or Canny().

On the left is when I cover the camera, you can see the weird artifact more clearly. In the middle is the artifact itself after passing through GaussianBlur(). It seems like it creates copies of the image and overlays them with itself. And on the right is when it's just grayscaled to show that THAT works properly. So I figure it's not something that's happening between C# and C++, it's something that happens only when I pass the frame through opencv's blur or gaussianblur or canny.

[image: example of artifact]

Here is the C# code in unity

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class camera : MonoBehaviour {
    [DllImport("tee")]
    public static extern void bw([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
        IntPtr data, 
        int width,
        int height);
    WebCamTexture back;
    Color32[] data;
    Byte[] byteData;
    Renderer rend;
    String test;
    Texture2D tex;
    GCHandle dataHandle;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        back = new WebCamTexture();
        back.Play();
        rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();

        tex = new Texture2D(back.width, back.height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
        data = back.GetPixels32();
        dataHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    }
    void OnDisable()
    {
        dataHandle.Free();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        back.GetPixels32(data);
        bw(dataHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), back.width, back.height);

        tex.SetPixels32(data);
        tex.Apply();
        rend.material.mainTexture = tex;
    }
}
```

and here is the C++ code that gets compiled into a DLL

```
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void bw(int data, int width, int height) {
        unsigned char * buffer = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(data);
        Mat mat = Mat(width, height, CV_8UC4, buffer).clone();
        Mat gray;
        cvtColor(mat, gray, CV_RGBA2GRAY);

        Mat blurred;
        GaussianBlur(gray, blurred, Size(3, 3), 2, 2);

        if (blurred.isContinuous()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < (width * height); i++) {
                unsigned char * pxl = buffer + 4 * i;
                pxl[0] = blurred.data[i]; //red channel
                pxl[1] = blurred.data[i]; //green channel
                pxl[2] = blurred.data[i]; //blue channel
                pxl[3] = (unsigned char)255; // alpha channel
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to OpenCV's documentation, the Mat constructor takes rows and cols as parameters, so you should switch the width and height parameters. See here http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat

Another thing, do you know how the images are stored in C#? Do they have any kind of data alignment(i.e. The rows aren't continuous)? Because that could also be an issue when you create the containing Mat.

I'm from my phone currently, I'll try to reformat my answer ASAP

EDIT: thinking about it, the thing about switching width and height when constructing makes sense only if both OpenCV and texture2D store images in row major order. I've checked here (http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/extracting-texture-data) and it seems it's like that.

Comment: omg, I feel like an idiot haha. I switched the width and height parameters in the Mat constructor and it fixed the whole problem. Thanks so much. What seems strange to me though, is that even though the parameters were switched, `cvtColor(mat, gray, CV_RGBA2GRAY)` still worked. That's what was confusing me.

Comment: It might be because cvtcolor is a per pixel operation, and the function accesses the pixels in a linear way (i.e. With a single for loop that goes from 0 to width*height). This way it technically doesn't matter if you switch the two dimensions (as long as the memory is continuous). On the other hand, gaussian blur does local processing in a neighborhood, which means that it needs to know exactly the width in order to "jump" between rows when indexing.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the way you are accessing `blurred` pixel value. You should access the channels values using the following instead

```
for (int i = 0; i < (width * height); i++) {
                unsigned char * pxl = buffer + 4 * i;
                pxl[0] = blurred.ptr<uchar>(i); //red channel
                pxl[1] = blurred.ptr<uchar>(i); //green channel
                pxl[2] = blurred.ptr<uchar>(i); //blue channel
                pxl[3] = (unsigned char)255; // alpha channel
            }
```

One other thing you can look into is the way opencv stores the pixel values versus pointer access of the data buffer (. You can test this easily by rotating the blurred image before accessing it and see if this gives you the correct output or creating `Mat mat = Mat(height,width,  CV_8UC4, buffer).clone();` instead.

And you are right about the blurred type, it should be one channel as the gray image.

Try the current code for another way of accessing the values in the blurred image

Comment: Would blurred have an rgb channel? Because when I looked at the docs for  blur() and gaussianblur() it says that the output is the same shape/size and type as whatever the input is, and when I index the input like that, it turns out fine. Could it be that the output isn't the same size shape or type as the input?You're onto something though, [this was the output when I tried your code](http://i.imgur.com/3GLOFTh.png). I'll try to keep playing around with it.